# Outlook Addin/VSTO/Redemption: CompareEntryIDs() returns false when comparing the StoreID of the same Exchange Shared Folder

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

My application saves the StoreID and EntryID of an Exchange Shared Folder to subsequently determine if two users have selected the same Exchange Shared Folder.

For the same Shared Folder, the Exchange users are given StoreIDs that, when decoded as a hex string, looks like this:

```
?8¡»å¡»+*VÂEMSMDB.DLLƒªfÍ›Èª/ÄZDC/o=TEST/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=UserA

?8¡»å¡»+*VÂEMSMDB.DLLƒªfÍ›Èª/ÄZDC/o=TEST/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=UserB
```

I would expect CompareEntryIDs() to return true when given the two different EntryIDs, as they refer to the same Shared Folder, but instead it is returning false.

Any ideas as to why CompareEntryIDs() is unexpectedly returning false?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first entry id is for userA, the second one is for userB. So they are different.

Comment: From the users' perspective, they have picked the same Shared Folder, so I would expect CompareEntryIDs() to return true. In Outlook UI, they both have chosen, for example, shared folder "\\Public Folders\All Public Folders\Top Level Folders\Our Shared Folder\".

Comment: For a PF store folder, the read state is saved on the per-user level, so different users will see the folder differently.

Comment: So in my example CompareEntryIDs() will never return true when given the StoreIDs of the same PF from two different Exchange users? How can I programmatically determine if the two Exchange users picked the same folder? By only comparing the EntryIDs (and ignoring the StoreIDs)?

Comment: What are you passing to CompareEntryIDs? Folder entry ids? Or store ids?

Comment: I use this expression to see if the two users selected the same PF:   `if(CompareEntryIDs(storeIdFromUserA, storeIdFromUserB) == true && CompareEntryIDs(entryIdFromUserA, entryIdFromUserB) == true)  {  //then they picked the same folder...  }`

Comment: Does it work if you compare only the folder entry ids?

Comment: I'll try that later this week and let you know. Given that both a StoreID and EntryID are required to uniquely identify an item in Outlook, I presumed I had to call CompareEntryIDs() on both to determine if the two users are referring to the same PF.

Comment: You should be fine with just the fielder entry id in this case - it is essentially the PR_SOURCE_KEY property of the folder (which is a 16 byte guid).